# Predis configuration in Laravel 5.2

Tags: configuration, installation, redis, laravel-5, predis

I am confused about the Predis setup (PHP client for Redis) in this case in a Laravel 5.2 project.
The **[documentation](https://github.com/nrk/predis#loading-the-library)** says you need to autoload it into composer to use it in the entire app without loading it on each page...

HOW? WHERE? WHAT? do I need to add or write to do this? I can't seem to figure it out as I know very little about installation en server configuration..

This is what I mean. This needs to go somewhere I assume

```
require 'Predis/Autoloader.php';

Predis\Autoloader::register();
```

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Another method

1. Download predis package from https://github.com/nrk/predis
2. Extract it
3. Copy the contents of folder into Laravel/vendor/predis/predis. Then folder structure will be
   [image]
4. In Controller

> ```
> class WelcomeController extends Controller
> {
>     public function index()
>     {
>         $client = new \Predis\Client([
>             'scheme' => 'tcp',
>             'host' => '127.0.0.1',
>             'port' => 6379
>         ]);
>         $client->set('foo', 'bar');
>         return $value = $client->get('foo');
>     }
> }
> ```

If redis is installed in your system, it will return value of 'bar'

Answer (score 0):

Please, read [documentation](https://github.com/nrk/predis#loading-the-library) careful:

> Autoloading is **handled automatically when dependencies are managed through Composer**, but it is also possible to leverage its own autoloader in projects or scripts not having any autoload facility:
>
> ```
> // Prepend a base path if Predis is not available in your "include_path".
> require 'Predis/Autoloader.php';
> Predis\Autoloader::register();
> ```

By default Laravel uses Composer to install dependencies, so you do not need to do anything special. Just add `predis/predis` as usual to your deps in composer.json. [Read more using of composer here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).

Comment: With `add predis/predis as usual to your deps in composer.json` I assume you mean the required section? Which I already did, with no success...

Comment: Oh will you look at that.. Going downstairs to make a cup of coffee and doing absolutely nothing to my computer the last 20 minutes solved my problem!